# window form: Adding Emoticons

Tags: .net, winforms

i am trying to develop a window form chat application using c# with asp.net 3.5 framework.

in that form i want to insert emoticons as we found in yahoo, hotmail etc messenger.

can anyone tell me how i can implement that thing as it is done in messenger.

please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a very hard working i got solution

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/csexrichtextbox.aspx

you can share it with other so that they can make applications as i need it.

thanks for your supports.

Answer (score 1):

If you want selectable text with inserted emoticon images, I think you have 3 relatively simple options:

1. Use a WebBrowser instead of a TextBox and create html from your text+images
2. Use a RichTextBox instead of a TextBox and insert your images into the RTF
3. Buy a third party advanced TextBox-ish control which offers the ability to override the drawing event

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use combination of ASCII characters.
You can try with ALT + numeric value to get some smileys. For e.g. combination of ':', '-' and ')' will give you :-). Ascii for ')' is ALT + 41.
similarly you can try different options.

Answer (score -2):

Emoticons in asp.net using simple javascript
http://csharpdemos.blogspot.in/2012/10/insert-smiley-images-automatically-in.html
And in windows forms
http://csharpdemos.blogspot.in/2012/10/how-to-insert-smiley-images-in.html